# How can I redirect Python's getpass() to stderr?

Tags: python, stderr

I'm trying to write a program that is going to print its prompts to standard error, and its output to standard out so that I can later manipulate the output.

I'm a bit new to python, but [the documentation for getpass()](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) shows I should be able to select a stream:

```
getpass.getpass([prompt[, stream]])
```

I have tried a variety of arguments to getpass, but I cant seem to get it to prompt in stderr. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
>>> password = getpass.getpass("Password", sys.stderr)
TypeError: unix_getpass() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: `getpass.getpass(prompt, sys.stderr)` doesn't work for you?  What happens instead of what you want, when you do that?  Note that password prompts generally should *not* be redirected away from the controlling terminal, unlike other prompts, and a lot of the point of `getpass` is that it gets this right.  (Plus it handles not echoing the password, of course.)

Comment: Can you explain to me what is wrong with redirecting just the prompt? When I type password = getpass.getpass("Password", sys.stderr) I get this:

TypeError: unix_getpass() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Any time you're going to demand a response directly from the user rather than from stdin, config files, or command-line arguments (and passwords are just about the only time you should do that in a Unix command-line program), you have to prompt them directly, so they know what's going on.  Imagine if I did '`ssh zack@otherhost noisy_command 2> /dev/null`' and ssh prompted me for a password on stderr instead of `/dev/tty` -- it would appear to hang for no reason.

Comment: Ah, right. I actually experienced this when I tried to redirect the output to an outfile. I think I will just write directly to the outfile instead. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the stream argument to `getpass.getpass()` was added in python 2.5, and isn't available in prior versions.

Comment: Aha! That's it. I forgot I was using Python 2.4, which is a rather crucial piece of information. Thanks a bunch.